# Running existing Selenium Webdriver scripts on iPad emulated browsers

Tags: ipad, selenium, selenium-webdriver, emulation

We have ample amount of Selenium Webdriver scripts supported to run on Windows Firefox, Chrome and IE. We wanted to run these scripts on iPad emulated browsers.

Is there anyway to accomplish this. If so, how to start with implementation. Please provide any reference URL's if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Using Appium you can achieve, however keep in mind that some Actions done on Mouse are different from that of iPad, They'll be Gestures.

It might be a bit of work because you will have to modify some scripts based on Gestures.

One more thing, What exactly are you looking to achieve is it more of Responsive testing or Function?

http://appium.io/

http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, we are more towards functional testing perspective.

Comment: Then i reckon you'll have to spend a fair amount of time in simulating gestures on your scripts running on iPads.